# Strange rendering problem

Tags: rendering

So I came across a problem : in the end of rendering my images smoothes out strangely. In material preview noises+fur are looking nice, but when I render it smudges all over. (My denoiser is not on)

What's the possible solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: what settings do you have for cycles? weird this looks like it was done with the denoiser after rendering tho...

Comment: Hello :). Make sure the denoise node isn't used in compositor. There are currently two different ways to enable denoising :).